# Is there a way to Search through Elastic Search to get all results that have an ID contained in an array of IDs?

Tags: elasticsearch

Been trying to find a way to do this for a couple days now. I've looked through '`bool`', '`constant_score`', '`filtered`' queries none of which seem to be able to come up with the result I want.

One that HAS come close is the '`ids`' query (does exactly what I described in the title of this questions) the one problem is that the key that I'm trying to search is not the '`_id`' value of the Elastic search index. Instead it is 'posterId' in the `index` below:

```
"_index": "activity",
"_type": "activity",
"_id": "<unique string id>",
"_score": null,
    "_source": {
    ...
    misc keys
    ...
    "posterId": "<QUERY BASED ON THIS VALUE>",
    "time": 20171007173623
}
```

Query that returns based on the `_id` value:

```
ids : {
    type : "activity",
    values : ["<unique string id>", ...]
}
```

as seen here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

How I want my query to work:

```
posterId : {
    type : "activity",
    values : [<list of posterIds>]
}
```

Returning all indicies that have posterIds contained in `"<list of posterIds>"`

< Edit > I'm trying to do this in one query as apposed to looping through each member of my list of posterIds because I also need to sort based on the time key and be able to page the query.

So, does anyone know of a built in query that does this or a work around?

---

Side note: if you feel like you're about to downvote this please just comment why, I'm about to be banned and I've read through all the guidelines and I feel like I'm following them but my questions rarely perform well. :( It would be much appreciated

Edit:

```
{
  "activity" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "activity" : {
        "properties" : {
          "-Kvp7f3epvW_dXSONzKj" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "actionId" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "actionType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "activityType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "attachedId" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "attachedType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "cardType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "noteTitleDict" : {
            "properties" : {
              "noun" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "subject" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "verb" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "posterId" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "segueType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "time" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1507678305995",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "<id>",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "5010199"
        },
        "provided_name" : "activity"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your index mappings and the query you tried. Also, some sample documents would help.

Comment: isn't the index mapping the first code chunk I have? also documentation related to the other queries I've used or indexing? I added the link the the one query I know works similarly to what I'm trying to achieve.

- Thanks for the comment

Comment: no, paste what you get from this: `GET activity/`
not documentation, i said "documents". The documents that you've stored in your index.

Comment: Is what I added what you're talking about?

Comment: yes, try a simple term or match query on posterId.keyword

Comment: I have, it produces the result in the first block. This isn't what I'm looking for however. What I'm trying to do is enter an array of keywords (they're actually unique string IDs) and be able to have any results that have posterId equal to any of the ones in the array is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a Terms Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This finds documents which contain the exact term Kimchy or elasticsearch in the index of the user field. You can read more about this here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

In your case you need to replace

1. the *user* with *posterId.keyword*
2. Kimchy and elasticsearch with all your posterIds

Keep in mind that a terms query is case sensitive and the keyword field does not use a lowercase analyzer (which means it'll save/index the value in the same case it was received)

Comment: Huh, when I tried this it never returned any results. I do think I've found a solution though. I'll post it once I push out this update and clean it up a bit.

Comment: @thoseguysintown check the following things: are you using the right case, Are you searching on the .keywords inner field, are you using a terms query and not a term query?